# Java net.Socket server sends data before client is ready to read it

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I have the server that sends current server's question to every new client. The question is being sent imidietaly after openning a socket and getting streams.

First client manages to get the whole data I send which means:

-String "QUESTION_COMING"

-The right Question Object

Each next client is blocked on client side readLine() method which means I execute readLine() method not before but after server sends it's question. When I put some sleep on a server-side socket thread, even 50ms, everything works fine.

Anyone has an idea how to know if client is ready for reading without putting sleep on a new socket  thread on server side?

Code:

```
------- SERVER SIDE --------

try {
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(os);
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        isRunning = false;
    }

    printWriter.println("QUESTION_COMING");
    printWriter.flush();
    logger.info("Sent phrase \"QUESTION COMING\"");


    try {
        assert gameManager != null;

        objectOutputStream.writeObject(gameManager.getCurrentQuestion());
        objectOutputStream.flush();

        logger.info("Sent " + gameManager.getCurrentQuestion());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



-------- CLIENT SIDE ---------

while(isRunning) {
        try {
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            logger.info("Got line - " + line);

            proceedIncomingString(line);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            isRunning = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

private void proceedIncomingString(String string) {
    try {
        if(string.equals("QUESTION_COMING")) {
            Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MySocket.class);
            logger.info("Starting reading object");
            Question question = (Question) objectInputStream.readObject();
            logger.info("Read object: " + question);

            Main.controller.setCurrentQuestion(question.getContent());
        } else if(string.equals("WRONG")){
        } else if(string.equals("CORRECT")) {
        }
    } catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {

        isRunning = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Logs:

------ SERVER ------

> 1 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO sample.ClientSocket - Starting socket -
>   Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=51861,localport=5000] 237
>
> 237 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO sample.ClientSocket - Sent phrase "QUESTION
>   COMING"
>
> 253 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO sample.ClientSocket - Sent
>   Question?
>
> 2264 [pool-2-thread-3] INFO sample.ClientSocket - Starting
>   socket - Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=51867,localport=5000]
>
> 2264 [pool-2-thread-3] INFO sample.ClientSocket - Sent phrase "QUESTION
>   COMING"
>
> 2264 [pool-2-thread-3] INFO sample.ClientSocket - Sent
>   Question?
>
> ------ FIRST CLIENT ------
>
> 0 [Thread-5] INFO sample.MySocket - Starting socket -
>   Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=5000,localport=51861]
>
> 238 [Thread-5] INFO sample.MySocket - Got line - QUESTION_COMING 238
>   [Thread-5] INFO sample.MySocket - Starting reading object
>
> 262 [Thread-5] INFO sample.MySocket - Read object: Question?
>
> ------ SECOND CLIENT ------
>
> 0 [Thread-5] INFO sample.MySocket - Starting socket Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=5000,localport=51867]